# .Net Core 2.0 solution with .Net Framework project dependencies - Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel'

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I have a `Core 2.0` solution in `VS2017` where my main project is Core 2.0. I then added 5 additional projects which target the `v4.0 Framework`.

The problem is that - once I instantiate the API class from the older project - it crashes on of those older project `References` with the following exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0
```

the line basically looks like this :

```
 _myAPI = new myCompany.Product.API();
```

I would like to move forward with this solution/project, but I think I may have to downgrade to `.net framework`.

I cannot change the older project references because those projects are shared across other solutions.

Do I need to downgrade to .Net Framework at this point ? In other words, a new solution file ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change your solution file but you will need to change your project file so it targets `net461` instead of `netcoreapp2.0`. You'll also need to reference individual assemblies instead of just `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`:

Change your Target Framework to `net461`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Reference the individual Asp.Net Core assemblies:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.0.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: So much is new in core 2.0, so I just ended up creating a brand new solution under the 4.6.1 framework and reusing some older code from another project. I guess my hope was to be able to move foward with `core 2.0`, while still adding 4.x project dependencies. It appears to be too much of an effort right now. Thank you.